# Why we cant extends class in Apex in Salesforce

Tags: apex

Why we cant able to extends class in Apex in Salesforce. If any doc is there please share the link.

Answer (score 4):

You can extend a class to provide more specialized behavior.
A class that extends another class inherits all the methods and properties of the extended class. In addition, the extending class can override the existing virtual methods by using the override keyword in the method definition. Overriding a virtual method allows you to provide a different implementation for an existing method. This means that the behavior of a particular method is different based on the object you’re calling it on...

```
// Extension for the Marker class
public class YellowMarker extends Marker {
    public override void write() {
        System.debug('Writing some text using the yellow marker.');
    } 
}
```

Source:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_extending.htm